# Google BigQuery: Sometimes TABLE_DATE_RANGE is unstable

Tags: google-bigquery

Sometimes a query using TABLE_DATE_RANGE fails in Google BigQuery.
But target table already exists and a failed query succeed by some retry.

Specific examples are as follows.

```
---------------------------------------
The Target Table
---------------------------------------
[ Dataset ID ]    my_dataset
[ Table ID ]      my_table_20170519
[ Creation Time ] 2017-05-20 02:00:52

---------------------------------------
The Executed Query
---------------------------------------
SELECT
  column1, column2, .....
FROM
  TABLE_DATE_RANGE(
    my_dataset.my_table_,
    TIMESTAMP('20170519'),
    TIMESTAMP('20170519')
  )
;

---------------------------------------
The 1st Execution and Result
---------------------------------------
[ Job Start Time ]  2017-05-20 02:00:57.513
[ Job End Time ]    2017-05-20 02:00:57.513
[ Result ]          Failure by "FROM clause with table wildcards matches no table"

---------------------------------------
The 2nd Execution and Result (Retry)
---------------------------------------
[ Job Start Time ]  2017-05-20 02:04:56.556
[ Job End Time ]    2017-05-20 02:04:56.556
[ Result ]          Failure by "FROM clause with table wildcards matches no table"

---------------------------------------
The 3rd Execution and Result (Retry)
---------------------------------------
[ Job Start Time ]  2017-05-20 02:06:43.937
[ Job End Time ]    2017-05-20 02:06:46.291
[ Result ]          Success
-
```

Incidentally a query using NO TABLE_DATE_RANGE always succeed.
(e.g. `FROM [my_dataset.my_table_20170519]`).
And other query almost simultaneously executed using same FROM clause sometimes succeed.

Of course, using retry can solve above example case.
But I'm worried that my_table_20170519 is ignored by a query using the following FROM clause.

```
FROM
  TABLE_DATE_RANGE(
    my_dataset.my_table_,
    TIMESTAMP('20170510'),
    TIMESTAMP('20170519')
  )
```

Dose anyone have idea to solve it?

---

I add two examples about this issue.

Example A:
Other query almost simultaneously executed using same FROM clause sometimes succeed.

```
----------------------------------------------
The Detail of Case
----------------------------------------------

- A program executes query "A" and query "B" in BigQuery.
- Both queries have the following FROM clause。

  FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(
    my_dataset.my_table_,
    TIMESTAMP('20170519'),
    TIMESTAMP('20170519')
  )

----------------------------------------------
The 1st Execution and Result
----------------------------------------------

Query "A"
  [ Job Start Time ]  2017-05-20 02:00:57.513
  [ Job End Time ]    2017-05-20 02:00:57.513
  [ Result ]          Failure by "FROM clause with table wildcards matches no table"

Query "B"
  [ Job Start Time ]  2017-05-20 02:00:57.507
  [ Job End Time ]    2017-05-20 02:01:09.537
  [ Result ]          Success


----------------------------------------------
The 2nd Execution and Result (Retry)
----------------------------------------------

Query "A"
  [ Job Start Time ]  2017-05-20 02:04:56.556
  [ Job End Time ]    2017-05-20 02:04:56.556
  [ Result ]          Failure by "FROM clause with table wildcards matches no table"

# Query "B" is NOT executed because it already succeeded.

----------------------------------------------
The 3rd Execution and Result (Retry)
----------------------------------------------

Query "A"
  [ Job Start Time ]  2017-05-20 02:06:43.937
  [ Job End Time ]    2017-05-20 02:06:46.291
  [ Result ]          Success

# Query "B" is NOT executed because it already succeeded.
```

Example B:
This issue sometimes occur after "NOT small" period of time.

```
---------------------------------------
The Target Table
---------------------------------------
[ Dataset ID ]    my_dataset
[ Table ID ]      my_table_b_20170519
[ Creation Time ] 2017-05-20 01:42:22

---------------------------------------
The Executed Query
---------------------------------------
SELECT
  column1, column2, .....
FROM
  TABLE_DATE_RANGE(
    my_dataset.my_table_b_,
    TIMESTAMP('20170519'),
    TIMESTAMP('20170519')
  )
;

----------------------------------------------
The 1st Execution and Result
----------------------------------------------
[ Job Start Time ]  2017-05-20 01:59:51.255
[ Job End Time ]    2017-05-20 01:59:51.255
[ Result ]          Failure by "FROM clause with table wildcards matches no table"

----------------------------------------------
The 2nd Execution and Result
----------------------------------------------
[ Job Start Time ]  2017-05-20 02:04:53.802
[ Job End Time ]    2017-05-20 02:04:57.684
[ Result ]          Success
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that TABLE_DATE_RANGE is using metatables (tables.list) to get list of tables that match criteria.
The problem is that while table data is available for querying immediately - the metadata is eventually available - meaning it takes time to get new table into the list.
If you would query that table directly right after creation you would not see this issue.

*Note: Above is assuming that you have this issue only after some "small" period of time right after new table created*

See also - [`Eventually consistent operations`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/consistency#eventually_consistent_operations) - I feel it is related

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The behavior of TABLE_DATA_RANGE you told is very intresting.
But it can NOT explains this issue for two reasons.

[1] Other query almost simultaneously executed using same FROM clause sometimes succeed.
[2] This issue sometimes occur after "NOT small" period of time.

(I add new examples about them to question.)

So, I think that issue occurs by other cause.
But thanks a lot.

Comment: agree - i would also expect that 16 minutes is more than enough for object to get available in the list.